# Using .htaccess to turn /index.php?page=X to /X

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've got a website that I've written from scratch, and the URL system is `/index.php?page=X`. I really want to be able to just type `/X` to get to that page. I've tried many ways I've seen on the Internet (over 10), and I can't find a way that works.

Also, I want to be able to do `/X` instead `/index.php?page=X&page2=X` (if they were all different variables)

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess (no redirection) \[REWRITEURL\] (folder to index.php)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807630/htaccess-no-redirection-rewriteurl-folder-to-index-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$  index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule  ^(\d+)\/to\/(\d+)$  index.php?page=$1&page2=$2

</IfModule>
```

I did not understand second part! I you can please explain!

Comment: By the second part, I mean that I have two variables on the URL, and I want to be able to just use one different word for those two URLs.